# MySQL database replication methods

Tags: php, mysql, replication

I am building a site to be used by clients it would store there basic information and projects or services there paying for to my company. The entire login + panel would run under SSL/HTTPS but my main concern comes down to Database Replication to prevent any events where something is lost.

Because some of the projects are hosted by me for the clients I need a way to assure there data is safe and sound. At the moment I am using Media Temple GS service but will move to DV service ones more customers start to pickup.

Based on my personal knowledge I was thinking of doing something like you would do with Hard Drives. Where there is a Master and then Slave. In SQL terms there would be a Master (Index) Database and there would be few Slaves (Cache) Databases.

But the question is, what would be the best way to replicate or to backup the Master onto Slave(s) and should I have additional GS or DV servers or is using the same server but with different DB name good enough?

**Edit**
I did some looking around MT and came accross there MySQL GridContainer which seems to do the same as owing 2nd server. Would this be a good alternative to actuall 2nd server?

Comment: There is no value in replicating a MySQL database running on a server onto another MySQL instance running on the same server. Configuring normal MySQL replication to replicate databases onto other servers is fairly straightforward - you just setup MySQL replication users that the servers can use remotely.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse you don`t understand replication used for backup. Replication for backup allows you to stop database (slave) and make complete backup without stopping master database. You can use same machine for that, because slave database is just a "snapshot" that you may move/copy to other server.

Comment: @Kamil I specifically said "running". Snapshot is totally different. The user is talking about live caches.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse OK, I thought you didn't know about replication+backup idea. And I used quotation marks intentionally where i wrote "snapshot".

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse sorry probably made my self bit un-clear by Cache I was referring to a Cache/Snapshot of the Index record.

Comment: @Kamil I was wondering would use of Cloud SQL service improve the redundancy and availability more over standard SQL replication and backups?

Comment: @user2108921 im not MySQL expert. Maybe read this article, about high availability MySQL solutions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea of replication for backup is replicating database to another database that you can stop and create full backup of that stopped database, while your production database is running.

You can use same server for creating backup files, but don't forget, that backup can ruin server performance (hard disk load). Additionally - when database is big, and you need historical backup files - you may need to compress backup files, and compression opertion will ruin your server performance totally.

You can't avoid second server, because you have to copy backup to another machine anyway (backup on same machine makes no sense).

So in general - it's better to replicate to another machine, which can be used also in crisis situations, when master server is down.

I found nice article about many solutions for high availability MySQL: [link to mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html).

Comment: Well MT does provide a powerful SQL pool. And as I said it will get the the point where secondary DV will be needed to provide data availability. But I am not sure how to do it in the present event.